# Submit animation issues in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, animated-gif

I've been dealing with this before but it seems like the problem came back. Let me explain.

I have a web page that lets a user upload a big file, after which it may also take several seconds for the ASP.NET server-side script to process it. In the meantime I wanted to show a loader/spinner animation in a web browser to prevent users from clicking the submit button again.

I used the following JQuery code:

```
$('#ButtonImportData').click(function () {
    $('.importSubmitSpinner').css('display', 'inline');
}
```

here's the HTML for the spinner image:

```
<img src="Graphics/spinner_big.gif" width="28" height="28" class="importSubmitSpinner" alt="Spinner" />
```

and here's CSS:

```
.importSubmitSpinner
{
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 6px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    display: none;
}
```

spinner_big.gif is a simple GIF file with an animation to signal for a user that a page is loading.

The above approach works in almost all browsers, except ... guess which one? Yes, IE! What happens in IE is that after a user clicks the ButtonImportData button the spinner is displayed but the animation stops immediately, basically giving a user a false indication that a page got hung up which prompts them to click submit again -- an opposite to what I wanted to do.

I stopped using IE a long time ago but evidently there is about half of the Internet community that still uses it. Man, how can people use that piece of *&^%? Anyway, that is not a question :) The question is, how to make this simple task work in IE and make my animation actually play?

PS. I've been testing it with IE 9 or whatever is the current "beauty of the web" for Windows 7.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to, ShadowScripter, I found a solution. Here's what worked for me:

1 Add the following to HTML to determine if we're running on IE (because we don't need to do this "hack" for any other web browser):

```
<![if !IE]>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var bNotIE = 1;
</script>
<![endif]>
```

2 We need to add ID to the img element:

```
<img src="Graphics/spinner_big.gif" width="28" height="28" class="importSubmitSpinner" alt="Spinner" id="imgSpinnerImport" />
```

3 Then to display the GIF animation:

```
$('#ButtonImportData').click(function () {
    //For "normal" browsers
    $('.importSubmitSpinner').show();

    if (typeof (bNotIE) == 'undefined') {
        //The following must be done only in case of IE
       //NOTE: We need to load the same file but with a different name
       //   because if you don't change the file name it won't work!
        setTimeout('document.images["imgSpinnerImport"].src = "Graphics/spinner_big_ie.gif"', 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of IE are you talking about? Have you tried jQuery BlockUI plugin. It seems to be browser compatible... http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to replicate your problem in any IE version.

[Here's the live example](http://jsfiddle.net/HPW9R/) I tested it in.

There can be a lot of different reasons why yours doesn't work.

- Other code might interfere
- GIF image is faulty
- Client computer; workload

Oh, also,

you can use `.show()` instead of having to do the `.css("display", "inline")` thing.
JQuery can identify which default display mode the element should have if none is specified.

Comment: That completely baffles me. What could be the case here? In this simple example it works just fine. I run the same script, same image, etc. from my script and it doesn't spin! In my case the page is composed from an ASP.NET script and if one opens it up to view as HTML it has a ton of stuff/junk added to it... Damn, MS!

Comment: In any case, the problem is not with what you provided. There's not much I can do to help unless you want me to debug your entire site, and I'm not really up for that tbh ;)

Comment: I updated it how it is in my code and it works there: http://jsfiddle.net/HPW9R/2 but why not in my page??? It just drives me nuts to waste time on this *&^%!!!!

Comment: Give [this](http://www.reddybrek.com/post/How-to-fix-an-animated-GIF-not-working-in-an-ASPPanel-when-using-Internet-Explorer.aspx) a look see.

Comment: It could be your browser's security settings, or if you've got a lot of stuff on one page, it might be stuck on a DOM read. Run your page through [here](http://validator.w3.org/) to check for any errors.

Comment: Thanks, you're the man! Your link gave me an idea and it seems to have worked for me (with some modifications though.) I posted the edit to my OP. But, man, how retarded IE is! How would someone even consider doing something like that without finding a clue???

Comment: @ahmd0 That's interesting. I'm curious why it happens on your site but not in the examples. So, you decided to use the refresh image code segment. I was hoping for a less obtuse solution... ;)

Comment: I can't really explain it, sorry... My guess is that some of MS code junk that comes with NET interferes with it. If you compile a stock NET web app and view its HTML in a browser there's a ton of stuff that is not rendered. That might be the key. The bottom line, stay away from NET if you can :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works great...

```
setTimeout(function() {
     ('.out').css("display","none");    
     $('#load').show();         
     return true;
}, 100);
```

Delay by a 100ms defore actually showing the loader image.

Comment: This is what the link above by @ShadowScripter does (check the comments.) By the way, still  not working in IE10, or whatever it is now...

Comment: This specific solution helped my non-asp related issue.  Thanks!